# Macbook can't resolve any domain names

Tags: snow-leopard, network, macbook-pro, dns

I have a 13" Macbook running Snow Leopard 10.6.6 which is unable to go to any URL on either my office or hotel networks.

I have no proxy or firewall enabled on the computer - and have connected to both networks in the past without issue.

If I ping google.com, it responds with 'cannot resolve google.com, unknown host' - however if I ping the IP it responds fine. I can also visit the IP in my browser and it goes to the page successfully.

I have rebooted, flushed my cache in several ways, tried to use Google's DNS (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4) all to no avail.

Any advice would be super!

Comment: also, my /etc/hosts file looks as it always has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has to do with Bonjour (mDNSResponder). **[Check out this page.](http://tech.karbassi.com/2007/11/06/leopard-turn-off-bonjour-mdnsresponder/)**

Run the following command in a Terminal:

```
ps aux | grep mDNS
```

This should tell you whether or not /usr/sbin/mDNSResponder is running. If it is not, run the following command to launch it:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/mDNSResponder
```

Comment: Thanks Jon! mDNSResponder was running, so I unloaded then loaded it - following the instructions on the link you provided - and it works perfectly!

Comment: Glad to hear, Dan! Cheers!